# How do I generate a regression on excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate a linear and quadratic regression of some data I have using vba. Simple enough right? The problem is when I use the linest function, I'm not getting the results I was hoping for (a 2d array containing the x values in the first column and the y values in the second column), and instead I'm receiving "Error 2015".

I know that linest is supposed to return the coefficients of a linear/quadratic regression, so I tried just creating a y=mx+b in my code to generate the arrays I want. I have yet to find success doing this.

Avg & P2 are the variables for the input data.

```
Dim lin() As Variant 'linear regression'
Dim quad() As Variant 'polynomial regression'
Dim RMSE1 As Single 'RMSE of linear regression'
Dim RMSE2 As Single 'RMSE of quadratc regression'
Dim nAvg() As Variant 'Avg values being looked at in current loop'
Dim nP2() As Variant 'P2 values being looked at in current loop'
Dim k As Single 'Ratio of RMSE1/RMSE2'
Dim linEstOut() As Variant
Dim linSlope As Single
Dim linB As Single
Dim quadEstOut() As Variant
Dim quadSlope As Single
Dim quadB As Single
Dim quadC As Single

For i = 2 To UBound(P2)
    ReDim Preserve lin(i)
    ReDim Preserve quad(i)
    ReDim Preserve nAvg(i)
    ReDim Preserve nP2(i)
    ReDim Preserve linEstOut(i)
    ReDim Preserve quadEstOut(i)

    nAvg(1) = Avg(1)
    nP2(1) = P2(1)

    nAvg(i) = Avg(i)
    nP2(i) = P2(i)
    'linear regression'
    linEstOut(i) = Application.LinEst(nAvg, nP2, 1, 0) 'linest returns a slope'
    linSlope = linEstOut(1)
    linB = linEstOut(2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(lin)
        lin(j) = (linSlope * nP2(j)) + linB
    Next j
    'quadratic regression'
    quadEstOut = Application.LinEst(nAvg, Application.Power(nP2, Array(1, 2)), True, False)
    quadSlope = quadEstOut(1)
    quadB = quadEstOut(2)
    quadC = quadEstOut(3)
    For j = 1 To UBound(quad)
        quad = (quadSlope * nP2(i) ^ 2) + (quadB * nP2(i)) + quadC
    Next j
    'RMSE'
    RMSE1 = (Application.WorksheetFunction.SumSq(lin) / i) ^ (1 / 2)
    RMSE2 = (Application.WorksheetFunction.SumSq(quad) / i) ^ (1 / 2)

    'Calculate K value'
    k = RMSE1 / RMSE2 'Greater than 1, non linear; close to 1, linear'

    'Determine if the region is linear or quadtratic'
    If k > 1 Then
        tpx = nP2(i) 'turning point x'
        tpy = nAvg(i) 'turning point y'

        Exit For
    Else
        End If
Next i
```

I have not gotten any output besides error messages yet. The desired output is two arrays containing the y-values of the linear/quadratic regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the code you have in your question: When dealing with regressions, you have to be aware that by default VBA arrays are starting at 0 and you need to specify when you (re)dim them that you want them to start at 1 which is the convention when doing regressions.

In you code, when you were running the line below, you had an empty value for nAvg(0) and nP2(0) which gave you the Error 2015 ([#Value cell error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/cell-error-values)).

```
linEstOut(i) = Application.LinEst(nAvg, nP2, 1, 0)
```

Hence, for anything that will contain regression data, I would suggest doing to redim them like this

```
ReDim Preserve nAvg(1 to i)
ReDim Preserve nP2(1 to i)
```

Side note: you could also `Option Base 1` at the top of your module to override the default at the module level, but your macros will start breaking if you copy them to other modules, so that is not recommended.

Regarding your comment and the second part of your question:

> For how to generate a polynomial regression with VBA, you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58425081/5958842).

Comment: Thanks! That answered my question, but now there's another problem. When I call linest for my polynomial fit, I get the coefficient that would be in front of x^2 and the constant, but I don't get the coefficient that would be in front of x. In this example my "quadSlope" and quadB are populated appropriately, with the slope and constant respectively, but quadC returns a "subscript out of range error". Could you offer help on what could be causing this?

Comment: @under267  I'm glad this helped. For what you mentioned in your comment, could you post it as a new question? I'll make sure to have a look.

Comment: I just forgot to. My bad!