# Type mismatch and expected values missing when using the LinEst function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, regression

This is a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57701442/5958842).

I'm working on producing a quadratic fit for a plot of data using Excel VBA. As is, when I call linEst, I'm getting the error "Type Mismatch". The one time it did work for me, if the formula for a quadratic equation is Ax^2 + Bx + C, I only got my A and C values to quadSlope and quadB respectively.

I have no idea what caused it to work the first time, so I can't provide much else on attempted solutions aside from the code posted below.

```
Dim quad() As Variant 'polynomial regression'
Dim nAvg() As Variant 'Avg values being looked at in current loop'
Dim nP2() As Variant 'P2 values being looked at in current loop'
Dim k As Single 'Ratio of RMSE1/RMSE2'
Dim quadEstOut() As Variant
Dim quadSlope As Single
Dim quadB As Single
Dim quadC As Single
ReDim quadEstOut(1 To 3)

For i = 2 To UBound(LaserP)
    ReDim Preserve lin(1 To i)
    ReDim Preserve quad(1 To i)
    ReDim Preserve nAvg(1 To i)
    ReDim Preserve nP2(1 To i)

    nAvg(1) = Avg(1)
    nP2(1) = P2(1)

    nAvg(i) = Avg(i)
    nP2(i) = P2(i)

    'quadratic regression'
    quadEstOut = Application.LinEst(nAvg, Application.Power(nP2, Array(1, 2)))
    quadSlope = quadEstOut(1)
    quadB = quadEstOut(2)
    quadC = quadEstOut(3)

    For j = 1 To UBound(quad)
        quad(j) = (quadSlope * nP2(i) ^ 2) + (quadB * nP2(i)) + quadC
    Next j


Next i
```

I'm looking for linEst to return the A,B, and C coefficients.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that if `LinEst` for a given data set returns an error, it cannot be assigned to your `quadEstOut` variable because that variable is `Dim`'d as a variant *Array*.

To fix taht issue, change to this:

```
'...
Dim quadEstOut as Variant

'...

'You don't need this, LinEst will override it anyway
'ReDim quadEstOut(1 To 3)

'...

'Get you fit
quadEstOut = Application.LinEst(nAvg, Application.Power(nP2, Array(2, 1)))
'Check for error
If IsError(quadEstOut) Then
    ' LinEst failed, what now?
Else
   ' rest of your code
End If
```

Note that I changed `Array(1, 2)` to `Array(2, 1)`.  As it was you are swapping the A and B coefficients.

<sub>Note that are are many other issues in your code.  I've limited this answer to address the question asked.</sub>

Comment: I figured out that linEst works on the first loop, and returns the correct values for A and C - the problem is that it's not returning a B, and not working in further loops. So changing Array(1,2) to Array(2,1) didn't really help me in this situation.

Comment: @under267 it that case, post a [MSCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including a _complete_ routine, a small sample data set that produces the error, expected results, actual results (including what you actually get in `quadEstOut`).

Answer (score -1):

If the size of the dataset is relatively small, it might be better to avoid using LinEst altogether and code the function yourself for more flexibility. The reason why I'm suggesting using this only with a small dataset is because it will require a few large matrix operations which can take a lot of time to perform in VBA.

Let's say that you have the following data with "Y" being in cell "A1"

```
Y           X       E
4534.6338   46.87   0.43
5600.2078   52.17   0.28
4688.4378   47.67   0.57
5758.1662   52.91   0.50
3495.2072   41.06   0.18
3328.3850   40.05   0.23
4305.5050   45.65   0.71
3706.3000   42.30   0.82
3589.7988   41.62   0.49
3890.6092   43.36   0.35
4178.5832   44.96   0.90
5049.7600   49.50   0.76
2864.8500   37.10   0.73
6077.8388   54.38   0.33
5581.5428   52.08   0.65
3653.0802   41.99   0.79
5981.6972   53.94   0.83
2925.7900   37.50   0.79
3284.7968   39.78   0.56
3311.8850   39.95   0.03
2945.5438   37.63   0.62
4603.1758   47.23   0.14
3655.7702   42.01   0.06
3353.0900   40.20   0.41
4638.4962   47.41   0.85
4018.8328   44.08   0.50
4134.5368   44.72   0.62
4993.1768   49.22   0.30
6623.0000   56.80   0.12
4860.1850   48.55   0.33
6401.9878   55.83   0.52
5966.3138   53.87   0.75
4260.7062   45.41   0.34
4567.1832   47.04   0.54
4752.7700   48.00   0.77
6255.4448   55.18   0.24
4776.4088   48.12   0.98
6409.1892   55.86   0.93
4907.5182   48.79   0.22
3614.8458   41.77   0.07
3832.4618   43.03   0.21
2919.8532   37.46   0.97
3608.9558   41.73   0.98
3557.2998   41.43   0.12
4110.6662   44.59   0.36
4443.2342   46.39   0.00
6128.7542   54.61   0.42
4931.7462   48.91   0.64
6207.0832   54.96   1.00
3358.2158   40.23   0.62
3473.9498   40.93   0.63
4949.4300   49.00   0.43
4732.9700   47.90   0.45
3600.3048   41.68   0.82
5933.4868   53.72   0.65
3199.6750   39.25   0.80
5326.5192   50.86   0.46
3450.6282   40.79   0.61
4801.6150   48.25   0.74
```

In this case our quadratic equation of form Y = AX^2 + BX + C + E has the following parametrisation:

[image]

Where E is the error that we don't observe and can't be explained by our linear model of Y = A*X^2 + B*X + C.

We could estimate the model using the following VBA procedure:

```
Sub OrdinaryLeastSquareEstimation()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Dim y() As Variant 'Independent variable
    y = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
    
    Dim x() As Variant 'Dependant variable
    x = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
    
    'Define regression parameters
    Dim n As Long
    n = UBound(x, 1)
    
    Dim p As Long 'Degree of the polynomial (customizable)
    p = 2
    
    'Generate the X matrix by putting our regressors side-by-side (ie. the constant = 1 = x^0, x, x^2, etc.)
    Dim Xmat() As Double
    ReDim Xmat(1 To n, 1 To p + 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To p + 1
            Xmat(i, j) = x(i, 1) ^ (j - 1)
        Next j
    Next i
        
    'Calculate the estimator vector
    Dim temp1() As Variant
    Dim temp2() As Variant
    Dim beta As Variant
    
    temp1 = Application.MInverse(Application.MMult(Application.Transpose(Xmat), Xmat))
    temp2 = Application.MMult(Application.Transpose(Xmat), y)
    beta = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(temp1, temp2)
    
    
    'Create equation to display
    Dim eqt As String
    Dim NbDigit As Long
    NbDigit = 4
    
    If beta(1, 1) > 0 Then
        eqt = "+" & WorksheetFunction.Round(beta(1, 1), NbDigit)
    Else
        eqt = WorksheetFunction.Round(beta(1, 1), NbDigit)
    End If
    
    For j = 2 To p + 1
        If beta(j, 1) > 0 Then
            eqt = "+" & WorksheetFunction.Round(beta(j, 1), NbDigit) & "*X^" & (j - 1) & eqt
        ElseIf beta(j, 1) < 0 Then
            eqt = WorksheetFunction.Round(beta(j, 1), NbDigit) & "*X^" & (j - 1) & eqt
        End If
    Next
    
    If Left(eqt, 1) = "+" Then eqt = Right$(eqt, Len(eqt) - 1)
    
    MsgBox "Estimated Equation:" & vbNewLine & eqt
    
End Sub
```

And you should get the following, which is pretty close the parameters from our model.

[image]

#### Method used

The code above uses the general matrix formula to calculate the Ordinary Least Squared estimate, which is the method used by the LinEst function as well:

[image]

[More details](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emrosenfe/soc_meth_proj3/matrix_OLS_NYU_notes.pdf)

#### Customization

- You could customize the variable p to be any integer which allows for any polynomial order.
- You can use the vector `beta` that contain to access the resulting
  coefficients from the regression. Make sure to use 2D references as
  it's a vector stored as a matrix of dimension p+1 by 1.